# Getting Beego to work on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, beego

I'm currently looking for a place where I can read about running the Beego (or similar GOlang) framework on AWS. Would anyone know a place?

Answer (score 1):

You have a [(Japanese- google translated) tutorial](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Fmacococo%2Fitems%2F7d36984ba824bb921ac5&edit-text=) to install Beego to AWS.
It doesn't involve anything special, except installing git, go and beego

```
sudo yum install git mercurial
yum install ld-linux.so.2

# Run curl -L -O https://go.googlecode.com/files/go1.2.1.linux-386.tar.gz as root
tar zxvf go1.2.1.linux-386.tar.gz -C / usr / local

/etc/profile.d/go.sh

export GOROOT = / usr / local / go
export GOPATH = / var / local / gocode
export PATH = $ PATH: $ GOROOT / bin: $ GOPATH / bin

go get github.com/astaxie/beego
go get github.com/beego/bee
```

The article "[Setup a website powered by Beego](http://reterwebber.wordpress.com/2013/12/08/setup-a-website-powered-by-beego/)" suggests a few other tools as well, like:

- [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) (Go Version Manager)
- [go.vim](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/vim/)